# IP's from Multiple Subnets on single Firewall Interface

Tags: windows, firewall, cisco, fortinet

I have FortiGate 200A Firewall.

I want to assign **two IP ranges to a single DMZ interface in the firewall**.

And than use them in a single windows server machine.

The ip address are:

72.80.206.192/27 (32 ip address)

72.80.208.0/27 (32 ip address)

**Is it possible? If so how?**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using public IP address ranges in your DMZ, it would probably be better to use a [private address range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) (i.e. 192.168.1.x /24).  Then NAT the public address space back to your server(s).  This will be both more secure and scalable.  It will also be a much more simple configuration on the server since you won't have to worry about asymmetric routing on the server itself.

Comment: I want to use the ip address to browse the internet from the server which is connected to this dmz , so i guess i need the public ip's , right?

Comment: No, do a hide NAT on the firewall and you will be able to browse the internet while still being more secure than giving the server a public IP Address.

Comment: You should be able to use hide-NATs to accomplish this, but my earlier comment of not using public addresses in your DMZ still stands.